# how to setup custom RPC endpoint for BSC on my server?

Tags: go-ethereum, bsc, rpc, full-node

is it possible to run a custom RPC endpoint on BSC?
if it is possible how can I do it on my one server?
I want to setup a RPC endpoint for my DAPP and I don't want to use third party RPC like quick node

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to set up your own private RPC endpoint for BSC, but you will need to run your own BSC node, which is quite resource-consuming. At least 2TB free space, 8 core CPU, 16 gigs of RAM. Looking at hetzner.com AX61-NVMe you will get such node for ~100 euros/month, but it will require frequent maintenance and might not be stable enough, though it may suit for development purposes.

You may want to take a look at third-party RPC services like rpcfast.com. They offer a free plan, which will be enough for testing and local development.